# how to ask for permittion on facebook app with graph api and codeigniter?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, graph

Ive been working on a application with Codeigniter and facebook... according with what ive seen on fb applications things should be easier... but my few experience with CI make it kinda hard... I wrote some code according some tips I read and documents... still I can make it work only for the profile which created the applications... the other profiles are simply dont ask for permittions and all returns null...

here is my code

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->library('facebook', 'config/facebook');
    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
        try {
           $data['profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
            }
    }

    if ($user) {
        $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
        $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }
    $this->load->view('home/home_view',$data);
}
```

I set the facebook library and config/facebook its just a configuration file... I should put something like

```
$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'req_perms' =>   'read_stream,email , user_birthday,user_about_me,friends_likes'
));
```

and should work (at least on php works) to when someone enters to my app ask to allow for give the info and all... still, nothing works, any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the api link the fields you need or you want to get from the user:

```
 $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,username,email');
```

It works in my application. You have to check as well if the data config you pass to the library is all correct. Something like this:

```
 $this->config->load('facebook', TRUE);
 $config = array(
       'appId'  => $this->config->item('facebook_api_id', 'facebook'),
       'secret' => $this->config->item('facebook_secret_key', 'facebook'),
       'fileUpload' => true,
 );
```

I hope this helps :-)